# How to Handle Windows Messages using QCoreApplication::winEventFilter

Tags: c++, qt, winapi

I am trying to implement winEventFilter in my QT application using QT Creator, QT SDK and Windows APIs

Declared the below in my class file

```
bool winEventFilter( MSG * msg, long * result )
{
    if( msg->message == WM_QUERYENDSESSION)
        DebugLog("shutdown");
    else
        DebugLog("Quit") ;    
}
```

I am calling the above method in the following way

```
MSG * msg;
long * result;

winEventFilter(msg, result);
```

When I logoff or shutting down my computer it never prints the log **shutdown**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The condition `msg->message == WM_QUERYENDSESSION` will never be true, since you're calling the function with an unitialized pointer (`MSG * msg`).

You need to pass a meaningful `msg`.

**However, this is not how you want to implement winEventFilter.**

`winEventFilter` is a method of `QCoreApplication` that you should use by reimplementing it in your `QCoreApplication` subclass. Then it will be called automatically for you.

See http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#winEventFilter for more details.

Comment: I thought its call a back function, so it will get the msg. Ok , I will try to correct it.

Comment: @JChan: Ah, I see, I think you misunderstood how you're supposed to implement it. You need to reimplement it in your `QCoreApplication` subclass (see my edit). You *don't* want to implement it as a separate function, since then it won't get called.

Comment: Qt 5 has replaced winEventFilter with installNativeEventFilter: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sourcebreaks.html#changes-to-qcoreapplication